# Performance monitoring tools for Google app engine

Tags: performance, google-app-engine

Can someone please provide suggestions over GAE cloud solutions to check health and performance of my application.

Some of the tools I found is:

1. Appstats
2. Hyperic Cloudstatus
3. gae_mini_profiler

I want to know if there is any solution people can suggest before I make decision from these three.

Comment: I've heard good things about `gae_mini_profiler`.

Comment: No idea what you're looking for.  Cloudstatus does something completely different from the other two.  Appstats requires practically no coding but only checks RPC calls.  gae_mini_profiler wraps appstats, but can also profile your app code.

Comment: @dragonx: Basically I want to know, are there solutions that are available in market to monitor health and performance of my app on google app engine. I know these three are unrelated but are there anything else that I can check. Found ProdEagle also which do the similar task.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/) together with [Google Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-trace) (both in Beta right now) probably is what you were looking for.